# How to pass a context on the second parameter on Intent contructor

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-context

I have a Service that its constructor receive a Context.
I want initialize that Service with method context.startService(Intent), passing an Intent as parameter.
Initializing the Intent with

```
intent = new Intent(context, GpsService.class)
```

But I need passing the Context to second parameter, because in this class I need the Context for initializing the LocationManager.

Or you can initialize the LocationManager without context, because I need to find the position with the LocationManager

Thanks

Comment: you need to pass the context to GpsService.class constructor?

Comment: Services have already access to a context if I remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.app.Service
```

Why would you want to pass an Context to an service? The service is an Context too!

Just use the `this` keyword, as the service will be cast to an Context!

Answer (score 0):

> class I need the Context for initializing the LocationManager.

Inside your `Service`, you can use the `getApplicationContext()` which will give you the reference to the global context object. So, you do not need to pass in an `Activity`'s context.

Comment: Beat me by the minute

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` keyword in services as services contain context already.
like this

```
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent,  int startId) {
        super.onCreate();
        // you can use this here as mentioned in the toast
         Toast.makeText(this,"Monitoring Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //ServiceHandler is the class name of this service
            SQLiteHelper sqh = new SQLiteHelper(ServiceHandler.this); 
    }
```